# Converting Int values into padded hours in Python with datetime

Tags: python, dictionary, jinja2, python-datetime

Let's say you have an object containing a schedule with start, break, lunch finish hours/minutes stored as integers:

```
schedules = {
        "employees": {
            "1":{
                "2018":{
                    8:{
                        1: {"day":1, "start_hours": 8, "start_minutes": 0, "1break_start_hours": 9, "1break_start_minutes": 30, "1break_end_hours": 9, "1break_end_minutes": 45, "lunch_start_hours": 11, "lunch_start_minutes": 30, "lunch_end_hours": 10, "lunch_end_minutes": 0, "2break_start_hours": 14, "2break_start_minutes": 0, "2break_end_hours": 14, "2break_end_minutes": 15, "finish_hours": 16, "finish_minutes": 30 }
```

Is there a way to render the hours/minutes as padded numbers (08 instead of 8 etc) on a page with jinja2 using the datetime module?

In other words, is there a bif or module that allows to convert an integer into padded number?

Comment: If you're on Linux, you can use `strftime` and `stpdtime`  with `%-M` and `%M` to convert between the two. On other systems, `%-M` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look like you're using `datetime` at all? But rendering padded numbers is very easy. There's two ways to do that Jinja (and in fact in Python in general):

The "old" style, with a `%`format string: `{{ "%02d:%02d" | format(start_hours, start_minutes) }}`

And the "new" style, using a `.format()` method: `{{ "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(start_hours, start_minutes) }}`

See https://pyformat.info/ for more about string formatting.